# SQLite Connection Open error inside SherlockFragment

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new in Android. I have a problem when start connection open to SQLite DB. Basically, it's connection open is work that calling from Android Activity. In my scenario, I had been used **SherlockFragment** Library. My problem is there. When I open the connection inside SherlocakFragement, I have the following error.

```
    03-03 09:12:52.320: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(2410): Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13175)
    at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2044)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    03-03 09:12:52.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
    at com.frontiir.MobileAgent.DAO.SqlAccessDAO.Connection_Open(SqlAccessDAO.java:152)
    at com.frontiir.MobileAgent.SyncPinFragment$1.onClick(SyncPinFragment.java:99)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:185)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-03 09:12:52.845: ERROR/android.os.Debug(2410): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
    03-03 09:12:53.090: ERROR/Launcher(2872): Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
```

Here my `SqlAccessDAO.java`

```
public class SqlAccessDAO {

public static DbHelper isp_dbHelper;
private final Context ispContext;
public static SQLiteDatabase ispDatabase;

public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           //some code
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           //some code
        );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_PIN + " (" +
           //some code   
        );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_SYNCHISTORY + " (" +
          //some code     
        );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_TOPUP_HISTORY + " (" +
           //some code     
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       //some code
    }
    }

    public SqlAccessDAO(Context c){
        ispContext = c;
    }

    public SqlAccessDAO Connection_Open() throws SQLException{
        isp_dbHelper = new DbHelper(ispContext);
        ispDatabase = isp_dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void Connection_Close(){
        isp_dbHelper.close();
    }

}
```

When I call open_connection inside the following call, the above error occurs.

Here my `SyncPinFragment.java`

```
public class SyncPinFragment extends SherlockFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

SqlAccessDAO sqlaccess = new SqlAccessDAO(getSherlockActivity());

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_pin_fragment, container, false);
        btnclick = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sync_pin);
        btnclick.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_sync_pin:
               forSync();
               break;
        }
    }

     private void forSync(){
         sqlaccess.Connection_Open();   //error occur in here when I breakpoint.
         //to do something here
         sqlaccess.Connection_Close();
     }
 }
```

Everything work fine in the following ***code snippet***.

```
public class LoginActivity extends SherlockActivity{
      SqlAccessDAO sqlaccess = new SqlAccessDAO(LoginActivity.this);
}
```

Comment: ispContext is probably null, that is usually the cause for this error.

Comment: @panini absolutely right bro. Say honestly, I don't know how to do it from Fragment.

Comment: From a Fragment? you should be able to use getActivity() to get the current Activity, have you tried that?

Comment: @panini Yes, already try it. But, not work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
 **add** this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL">
```

2.
 **Replace** this line :

```
SqlAccessDAO sqlaccess = new SqlAccessDAO(getSherlockActivity());
```

with this

```
private SqlAccessDAO sqlaccess;
```

In the `forSync`() method, add the following line

```
sqlaccess = new SqlAccessDAO(getActivity());
```

Comment: May I know where `DBAdapter` come?

Comment: sorry it's **SqlAccessDAO** not _DBAdapter_  (DBAdapter from another project) @K-THIHA

Comment: Wooowwwwwwwwww. That's incredible. I got it with your code snippet. Thanks you.